# Rest helper codeceptjs and docker

Tags: rest, docker, codeceptjs

I am running REST Helper of Codeceptjs and Docker for API Testing but when I run it, it only show all passed and execution time is always 0ms

Output:

```
PS D:\work\testtt> docker-compose run --rm codeceptjs
CodeceptJS directory has been found.
CodeceptJS v2.0.4
Using test root "/tests"

Test @regression --
  ✔ Add Scholarship For Application @kss3 in **0ms**
  ✔ Add Accommodations For Application @kss3 in **0ms**
  ✔ Add Airport Transfer For Application @kss3 in **0ms**
  ✔ Add Booking Others @kss3 in **0ms**
  ✔ Add Booking Insurance @kss3 in **0ms**
```

My docker-compse file :

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  codeceptjs:
    image: codeception/codeceptjs
    environment:
      - CODECEPT_ARGS=-c ApiCarrotEnv.conf.js --grep kss3 
    volumes:
      - .:/tests
    container_name: docker-nightmare
```

But if I run without docker it ran normally.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar but not the same problem when running my dockerized codeceptjs tests, usually that error indicates to me that the runner can't find the grep @s. I was able to resolve it by running it on the Kubernetes templates for selenium here -https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/selenium